# Hotkey to switch WinXP between screens?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, hotkeys

Without an add-on, is there any key combo that will move an active window to the alternate screen in a dual-headed display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an add-on in XP, there isn't one. This has just been implemented in Windows 7 though:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to move the window to the left monitor

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to move the window to the right monitor

Comment: Yeah, like my company would *ever* upgrade me :O  Thanks.